# How to find a substring in a field in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

How can I find all the objects in a database with where a field of a object contains a substring?

If the field is A in an object of a collection with a string value:

I want to find all the objects in the db "database" where A contains a substring say "abc def".

I tried:

```
db.database.find({A: {$regex: '/^*(abc def)*$/''}})
```

but didn't work

**UPDATE**

A real string (in unicode):

```
Sujet  Commentaire sur  Star Wars  Episode III - La Revanche des Sith 1
```

Need to search for all entries with Star Wars

```
db.test.find({A: {$regex: '^*(star wars)*$''}}) not wokring
```

Comment: As @derick points out, if you want to look for "any string of characters", you need `.*` : `.` for any (single) character, `*` for "the previous thing any number (including zero) times. The `(star wars)*$` you have would match "star warsstar warsstar wars" but not "star wars is great".

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
db.database.find({A: {$regex: '/^*(abc def)*$/''}})
```

You should do this:

```
db.database.find({A: /abc def/i })
```

^* is not actually valid syntax as ^ and $ are anchors and not something that is repeatable. You probably meant ^.* here. But there is no need for ^.* as that simply means "Everything up to the character following" and (abc def)* means "0 or more times "abc def", but it has to be at the end of the string, because of your $. The "i" at the end is to make it case insensitive.

Comment: note that using '^' helps speeding up regex query since indexes will be effective only in this form (see the bottom of the page at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but does '^*' make any sense? Shouldn't it be '^.*'? To me '^*' reads "zero or more beginnings of the line", of which there is only and always one, and it looks to me like it __doesn't__ allow characters between the beginning of the line and the rest of the regex...

Comment: @drevicko, you're right. That was a typo in my answer. I've clarified it.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you've got an index on `A`, it will only be used if [the regex is anchored to the start of the line and is case sensitive](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/) - ie: `/^.*abc def/`

Comment: drevicko, that's not correct. The first part of the regex match needs to be *static* otherwise it sill will have to do a full collection scan. Ie: ^abcdef works well to use only part of an index, but ^.*abcdef does not. In the first case, a range query is done first (>= "abcdef & < "abcdeg") and then the regexp is run on each of the values that comes out of that.

Comment: How to write Spring Data mongo repository method for this? Please guide

Comment: -1 because your answer is really misleading on the error OP made. And you are implying he is using NodeJS or mongoshell (with the regex format you offer), however this won’t work with python or mlab for instance. So I’d propose the query `{A: {$regex: 'star wars', $option: 'i'}}`, or luisCarlos’s answer

Comment: How (in)efficient is this?

Answer (score 57):

Just use the string "Star Wars" and [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) will do the rest

```
db.test.find({A: {$regex: 'Star Wars'}})
```

Comment: this is great, but this one is case sensitive

Comment: Case insensitive: `db.test.find({A: {$regex: 'Star Wars', $options: "$i"}})`

Answer (score 9):

`$regex` is too expensive/slow on large collections.

I'd suggest to leverage aggregation framework and [$indexOfCP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/).

```js
db.test.aggregate([{$match: 
    {$expr: { $gt: [{ $indexOfCP: [ "$A", "Star Wars" ] }, -1]}}
    }, {$project: {A:1}}])
```

For case-insensitive search you may add `$toUpper` to the mix and search for `STAR WARS`.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but why do you think that it has better performance than a regex?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
db.test.find({"A": {'$regex': '.*star wars.*'}})
```

Comment: As pointed out in other answers, `.*` is superfluous/meaningless here and only increases computational costs.

Answer (score 2):

this one uses the aggregation syntax:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  {$match: 
    {
      title: {$regex: 'Star'}
    } 
  }
] )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// executes, name LIKE john and only selecting the "name" and "friends" fields
db.collection.find({ name: /john/i }, 'name friends').exec();

// passing options
db.collection.find({ name: /john/i }, null, { skip: 10 }).exec();
```

Comment: I like this because it does it with "Native" Strings vs Regex I tested this in Compass

Answer (score 1):

```
db.getCollection('your_collection_name').find({key:{$regex: "value"}})
```

Example:-
your_collection_name:

```
users (let's say), key: email, value: @gmail.com,
```

now query is

```
db.getCollection('users').find({email:{$regex: "@gmail.com"}})
```

Then you will get all users which contain `@gmail.com` in the email

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax to do the substring search in mongoDb.. the $options : "i" makes the search case-insensitive .. if you want case sensitive search remove the options argument.

```
    db.collection("test")
    .find({ name: { $regex: subStringName, $options: "i" } })
```